# Qt / C++ internal API design for slightly similar web services

Tags: c++, api-design, qt

in [my application](http://www.dennogumi.org/projects/danbooru-client/) I provide a Qt/C++ wrapper to certain web services based on the Danbooru software. Basically the API wraps a series of REST calls and produces / parses the JSON responses to display this in an application.

Links to the source which wraps the web API:

- https://git.dennogumi.org/kde/danbooru-client/blob/master/src/libdanbooru/danbooruservice.h
- https://git.dennogumi.org/kde/danbooru-client/blob/master/src/libdanbooru/danbooruservice.cpp

The basic structure of the `DanbooruService` in these files involves keeping track of the "page" being shown, the filters for displaying what's being downloaded or not, and some methods that handle retrieving results from the API (cf. `getPostList`, `getPoolList` in the above links).

Now, due to the history of said web software there are a number of forks around, *each* with a slightly different API involved. As the one I designed now works with only two of the most popular, I thought I'd implement support for others. One of the issue is that not all web APIs support all operations.

And here we come to the question, which is at the moment more about design, than proper programming (and that's why I posted it here): what would be the "less worse" way to go about it?

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

1. Avoid cramming everything in a single class as it's already too complex as it is
2. Make the `*Service` class an abstract base class with basic methods that need to be implemented in the subclasses
3. Add to the base class and to the subclasses an enum that identifies the "capabilities" of each service

OR

1. Scrap the base class idea altogether and use different classes with capabilities as point 2 above, but I'm not sure it would ease complexity.

At the moment however I'm using some hardcoded URLs for APIs, and yes, those change too between versions.

Given these requirements (I can provide some snippets inline, but I put links as the code is large), what would be a good design to make this less headache-inducing?

EDIT: Forgot to say, *none* of this is public, so I can break things as I want.

Comment: Are your users aware of the URL and the various API variants? And if not, how are you planning to deal with the changes in URLs?

Comment: The URLs are currently static members in the class and are only used internally. The API users just call the relevant methods, with no knowledge of the URLs and the APIs. Everything else is encapsulated in the class.